# Conditionally replace spring boot config yml property

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I would like to replace a configuration yml property using a condition based on environment variables:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username:${ENV} == 'PROD' ? ${USER_PROD} : ${USER_TEST}
    password: ${ENV} == 'PROD' ? ${PWD_PROD} : ${PWD_PROD}
```

Is there any way I can do this inside my application.yml or programmatically?

I have not faced this situation before

Comment: Don't. Instead provide profile specific property files or pass the password/user at runtime. Else you endup with programming in properties or yaml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way of doing this is to use different `application.properties` file each representing a "profile".

Then you can override the desired properties based on the profile and run the application using that profile using `-Dspring.profiles.active`.

A useful guide on the following [link](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/profile-specific-properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can use separate config files and properties for different Spring Profiles.

please read this guide for more info: [Guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests-override-properties)